What is the difference between the btos and ztos in TosState?
enum TosState {         // Describes the TOS (Top of Stack) cache contents
  btos = 0,             // byte, bool TOS cached
  ztos = 1,             // byte, bool TOS cached
  ctos = 2,             // char TOS cached
  stos = 3,             // short TOS cached
  itos = 4,             // int TOS cached
  ltos = 5,             // long TOS cached
  ftos = 6,             // float TOS cached
  dtos = 7,             // double TOS cached
  atos = 8,             // object cached
  vtos = 9,             // TOS not cached
  number_of_states,
  ilgl                  // illegal state: should not occur
};

Does the JVM's operand stack top ever contain a bool value? Also, the comments for ztos and btos here are exactly the same.Specifically, I would like to understand the difference between btos and ztos.
Does the JVM's operand stack top ever contain a bool value? Also, the comments for ztos and btos here are exactly the same.Specifically, I would like to understand the difference between btos and ztos.
